# Labels not aligning with controls

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a control which should line up but I don't understand why not. It should display a label textbox then a button the textbox and button line up ok but the label does not.

Also, I would prefer the two buttons to show side by side also how does one tell the textbox to take up if not all of the width properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"

             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="WMS.Controls.EntryWithLabels">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="2">

            <Label x:Name="FieldText" ></Label>
            <telerikInput:RadEntry x:Name="FieldValue" WidthRequest="200"  WatermarkText="FieldCaption"/>
            <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="button" Text="..." />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

View that the control is consumed in

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="Item" CaptionText="Item"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="Description" CaptionText="Description"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="UOM" CaptionText="UOM"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="From Whse" CaptionText="From Whse"><EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="Avaiable" CaptionText="Avaiable"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="To Whse" CaptionText="To Whse"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="To Bin" CaptionText="To Bin"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="Batch" CaptionText="Batch"></EntryWithLabels>
        <EntryWithLabels TitleText="Quantity" CaptionText="Quantity"></EntryWithLabels>

        <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="button" BackgroundColor="#fdd57d" Text="Close" />
        <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnClear" BackgroundColor="#fdd57d" Text="Clear" />
        <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnSave" BackgroundColor="#fdd57d" Text="Save" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: VerticalTextAlignement="Center" ?

Comment: @Roubachof it more the fact the label is sitting top most and not inline with the textbox line

Comment: yes I understood, VerticalOption="Center"

Comment: @Roubachof worked how would i get all the textboxes to look the same width though you see the way they looked skewed.

Comment: use a Grid instead of a StackLayout

Comment: Use a Grid, or assign a fixed width to the Labels.  And use a Horizontal StackLayout to arrange your bottom row of buttons

Comment: A grid will give you better control over how your items should be arranged horizontally. Also it will reduce layouting time, as the stacklayout needs more layout passes until the final widths of your elements have been determined.

Comment: @MarkusMichel seems like a logical approach could you show a demo

Comment: @rogue39nin see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change your EntryWithLabels view to use the following Xaml:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="WMS.Controls.EntryWithLabels">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="FieldText" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
            <telerikInput:RadEntry x:Name="FieldValue" WidthRequest="200"  WatermarkText="FieldCaption" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="button" Text="..." Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

The width definitions of the column are relative, since I didn't compile and view the code, you might need to adapt the values. With the current definition, the first and last columns would use 1/5th of the screen's width and the center column 3/5ths.

Another variant would be to set the first column to a fixed with of 210 (leaving a bit of margin for your label). Then the other columns would take 3/4th and 1/4th of the remaining space.

```
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Last but not least you could also set the first and last column to a fixed value.

```
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

In that case the center column would use all the remaining screen width (screen width - (2* 210) available.